# How to have more than one tty console in yocto?

Tags: yocto

After building the yocto genericx86-64 target.

It can boot, login with root.

However, it only has 1 tty, I can't press ALT + F2 / F3 .... to open a new tty console.

How to setup yocto to have more than one tty console?

Answer (score 0):

Your machine configuration sets the variable SERIAL_CONSOLES, currently probably to value "115200;ttyS0". You should be able to modify that or override it in your local.conf with

```
SERIAL_CONSOLES = "115200;ttyS0 115200;ttyS1"
```

to add another tty.

Comment: This should be serial console, but I need consoles on VGA screen by pressing ALT+F2 ...etc.